# Angular 11: Ng-popover close automatically when selecting date from Ng-popover

Tags: javascript, html, angular, popover, auto-close

In my angular 11 project.

When I am trying to use multiple ng-popover in one screen, when open one pop-over and then open another popover on the same screen, first ng-popover closed by its default ng-popver functionality.

But when I am implementing date-picker inside ng-popover, the ng-popover automatically closes when I am choosing date form date-picker.

Using This
`popover-trigger="'outsideClick'"` & `popover-trigger="focus"`

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are using [container]="'body'" in input ngbDatepicker.

Here an example where it works as expected.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngbdatepicker-inside-ngbpopover